# ListView doesn't contain a definition for 'Add'?

Tags: c#, xamarin

Minor problem I have. I have been trying to find the error, but I don't find it, if you can point it out, or give me some correction that would be great. As for the code here is it:

```
using UIKit;

namespace App10
{
public class Application
{
    // This is the main entry point of the application.
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var listView = new ListView();
        listView.ItemsSource = new string[] {
        "Trainer 1",
        "Trainer 2",
        "Trainer 3",
        "Trainer 4",
        "Trainer 5",
        "Trainer 6",
        };  

    listView.ItemsSource.Add("Trainer");
```

Comment: Well aside from anything else, no you *can't* add items to an array. But You're actually trying to call add on `listView.ItemsSource` anyway... what's the declared type of that property?

Answer (score 6):

That is because an array does not have a Add function. You should use List.

In WPF, you can best use an `ObservableCollection`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var listView = new ListView();
    var myTrainers = new ObservableCollection<string>() {
        "Trainer 1",
        "Trainer 2",
        "Trainer 3",
        "Trainer 4",
        "Trainer 5",
        "Trainer 6",
    };  
    listView.ItemsSource = myTrainers;

    myTrainers.Add("Trainer");
}
```

Comment: do I need to put that code into the already presented code? just a quick question.

Comment: im writing now because i dont know if you got my reply

Answer (score 1):

`ListView.ItemsSource` is an `IEnumerable`. Whatever you assign to it, you can't call `Add` on it, unless you cast it.

The best option you have is to bind the `ItemsSource` to a property of type `ObservableCollection`. In that way, you can still use the list as you want, and the view can bind to it.

Create a view model with a list property. Then assign that view model in the view.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you initializing a listview in Main.cs in iOS.  ListView is an Xamarin.Forms component. And the datasource to a list view must be ObservableCollection In Xamarin.Forms

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding/